# Checking data if exist in Database VB.Net

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access-2010

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\users\sjmi.alfie\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Sample Ko\WindowsApplication4\MySample.accdb"
        If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            con.Open()
            MsgBox("connection is open", vbInformation)
        Else
            MsgBox("connection is close", vbCritical)
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub closeButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles closeButton.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub regButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles regButton.Click

        Dim strsql As String
        Dim numrows As Integer
        strsql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Sample WHERE StudNo = " & TextBox1.Text & ""
        Dim objcmd As New OleDbCommand(strsql, con)
        numrows = objcmd.ExecuteScalar()  <<<< Error "Data type mismatch in criteria." 

        If numrows > 0 Then
            MsgBox("Record Exists", vbInformation, "Add")
        Else
            Dim myadapter1 As New OleDbDataAdapter("INSERT INTO [Sample] ([StudNo], [FirsName], [LastName]) VALUES ('" & TextBox1.Text & "', '" & TextBox2.Text & "', '" & TextBox3.Text & "')", con)
            Dim mytable1 As New DataTable
            myadapter1.Fill(mytable1)
            MsgBox("Success!!")
        End If
        con.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

please help me. Thanks

Comment: Tag your code properly and explain the problem clearly, please.

Comment: Please indent your code properly

Comment: @varocarbas : as part of my review code i commented the above statemen, i mean that includes your stmt also, i just requested OP with Please. Though i am not a expert in VB.NET, i would like to help the experts like you, without wasting their time in reading a cluttered code

Comment: @varocarbas i mentione my answer in my previous comment itself

Comment: Summary of deleted comments: I have highlighted a behaviour which I consider pointless (perhaps a bit aggressively; but well... being tolerant with pointless behaviours is not my style). After not reaching any understanding (+ having suffered coordinated "attacks" from other places; nothing too serious, just funny fanatismus) I came to the conclusion that better talking to Siva and/or SenthilKumar as less as possible (ideally, nothing), unless while they will continue showing what I call (better omitting this part, don't want censure :)). And this was it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```vb
strsql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Sample WHERE StudNo = ?"
Dim objcmd As New OleDbCommand(strsql, con)
objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TextBox1.Text)
numrows = Convert.ToInt32(objcmd.ExecuteScalar())
```

It's called a "parameterized query", and it is the preferred way of doing what you intend.